# GF is the radical axis

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, power-of-the-point

Given $\Delta ABC$. $D,E$ lie in $AC,AB$. $BD \cap CE =$ {$F$}. $(ADE) \cap (ABC) = ${$G,A$}. Let $M,N,P,Q$ be the midpoint of $BC,ED,EB,CD$, respectively. Prove that $G$F is the radical axis of $(GMN)$ and $(GPQ)$

[image]

Comment: In a speacial case: $F$ lies on $(ADE)$, the problem will be much easier. It's not hard to show that $GF$ goes pass the midpoint of $BC$ and that midpoint lies in $(APQ)$ ...

Comment: Fun problem.  There is rich structure, but I haven't figured out the answer yet.  Did you make this up or did you get it from somewhere?

Comment: Just a little from me. I did some development on a problem. And still hope for another solutions which don't use the barycentric :D

Comment: Check out https://www.geogebra.org/m/N3ufQb6k.  I thought that intersecting one diagonal with one circle, and the other diagonal with the other circle would create 4 points that were cyclic. And they are, but I can't prove it.  But this would solve your problem.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u307658h1635365p10281828
here's what I found

Comment: AOPS is perhaps a better place to get answers to this type of problem.  Since someone pointed to a paper on Miquel and E-P points, I should mention this: https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/Quadri-figures-group/conversations/messages/2989 In particular, the Miquel point, Quadrilateral Centroid and Gergonne-Steiner point are collinear. GS and EP points are reflections of each other wrt Centroid, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Hope you find an answer.  If you do, please write it up here as well.

Comment: Btw, doesn't Theorem 10 in http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2014volume14/FG201413.pdf address your original question?  It looks like their pseudocircumcenter is the Gergonne-Steiner point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've translated your problem into the context of the so-called [complete quadrangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_quadrangle).  The geometry of this configuration has been studied for centuries, and is associated with such gems as the [nine-point conic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-point_conic).  There is a website devoted to it and its landmark points, lines, circles, and conics - the [**ENCYCLOPEDIA OF QUADRI-FIGURES (EQF)**](https://chrisvantienhoven.nl/mathematics/encyclopedia) , also available as a [PDF](https://chrisvantienhoven.nl/files/28/EQF/2/Encyclopedia-of-Quadri-Figures.pdf).

[image]

In the figure above, the vertices have been relabeled.  The base quadrangle vertices are $A,B,C,D$, and opposite sides intersect at $X_2,X_3.$  Your original triangle $ABC$ becomes $X_2BC$, and circles $(GMN)$ and $(GPQ)$ become  $(X_3M_{BC}M_{AD})$ and $(X_2M_{BD}M_{AC})$.  Note that each circle corresponds to a pair of opposite sides of the quadrangle and their intersection and midpoints.  By symmetry, there is a third circle  $(X_1M_{DC}M_{BA})$.  Because there are three pairs of opposite sides and their corresponding circles, the assertion to be proven -- that $X_1$ is on the radical axis $R_{23}$ of $(X_3M_{BC}M_{AD})$ and $(X_2M_{BD}M_{AC})$ -- has similar statements for the other $X_i$.

Although much of the geometry of the complete quadrangle can be developed with synthetic methods, it appears that the power tools of choice are analytic.  One approach, for example, is to use barycentric coordinates, and to express points and loci in this form.  Although there is rich geometry in OP's question, a synthetic answer has eluded me, and [so we turn to barycentric coordinates](http://web.evanchen.cc/handouts/bary/bary-short.pdf).

Using methods described in the aforementioned EQF we choose the triangle $ABC$ as a base, so that $A,B,C$ have coordinates $(1:0:0),(0:1:0),(0:0:1)$ respectively, and we designate the coordinates of the fourth point $D$ as $(p:q:r)$ and the sidelengths of the base triangle as $a,b,c$.  Then we build up the lines and points of the diagram.  For example, the lines $AC$ and $BD$ are represented by $y=0$ and $-r x+p z=0$.  And $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are $(-p:-q:0),(-p:0:-r),(0:-q:-r)$.  (The calculations can be automated using a Mathematica notebook for barycentric coordinate calculations available [here](http://garciacapitan.blogspot.com/2021/01/coordenadas-baricentricas.html)).

Cutting to the chase, the equation of the radical axis $R_{23}$ is

$$
\begin{align}
q (-c^2 p q+a^2 p r-c^2 p r+b^2 q r-c^2 q r+a^2 r^2+b^2 r^2-c^2 r^2) &x \\
 + p (c^2 p q-a^2 p r+c^2 p r-b^2 q r+c^2 q r-a^2 r^2-b^2 r^2+c^2 r^2)& y \\
-(p+q+r) (a^2 p q-b^2 p q-b^2 p r+a^2 q r) &z  =0\end{align}
$$

Although this is a formidable equation, it is easy to see that the coefficients for $x$ and $y$ have a common factor, and that $X_1=(-p:-q:0)$ is on this line.

With acknowledgements to the EQF community for their assistance.

Answer (score 1):

A synthetic proof can be found in 
Michal Rolinek and Le Anh Dung,
*The Miquel Points, Pseudocircumcenter, and
Euler-Poncelet Point of a Complete Quadrilateral*, Forum Geometricorum, 14 (2014) 145--153.  Available at http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2014volume14/FG201413.pdf.

See the proof for Theorem 10.  Figure 7 corresponds to the diagrams given by OP and in answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2753547/1257, although it is flipped left to right.

It is generally frowned upon to answer questions with links, but the given citation should be quite stable, and the proof is too lengthy to reproduce here.